# How to get latest post ID in functions.php?

Tags: php, functions

I'm trying to get latest post ID.

And then store that ID into user_meta.

Right now I have this code:

```
add_action('wp', 'bt_update_user_homepage_meta');
function bt_update_user_homepage_meta () {
    
// Get user id
$user_id = get_current_user_id();

// Get newest post ID
        //WP_Query Arguments
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page'    => 1,
    'meta_key'          => 'usp-custom-1',
    'meta_value'        => 'question',
);

//Execute WP_Query (Results placed in $the_query)
$the_query = new WP_Query($args);
$id = get_the_ID();
     
//The WordPress Loop
if ($the_query->have_posts()) { //Check if there are any posts returned in $the_query

    while ($the_query->have_posts()) { //Loop through posts returned in $the_query
        $the_query->the_post();

//Update user meta with the latest post ID
         if ( is_page( array( 'home' ) ) ) update_user_meta($user_id, 'pagehome', $id);
    }

} 

//Reset WordPress Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

But it stores current post ID, instead of the latest post ID.

Been struggling with this for a while.

I know I maybe missing something in the code.

Need help.

Comment: `$id = get_the_ID();` is outside the loop. It needs to be after `$the_query->the_post()` to get the ID of the post inside the query.

Comment: You should also elaborate on what you're ultimately trying to achieve. Writing to the database on every request is not a good idea.

Comment: Brilliant! it worked simply by putting `$id = get_the_ID();` inside the query! Thanks Jacob. I thought I was missing something very small. I have also used `if ( !empty( $user_id ) && is_page( [ 'home' ] ) )` to process only logged in users. THANKS AGAIN!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code that should probably work for you:

```php
function bt_update_user_homepage_meta() {

    // Get user id
    $user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( !empty( $user_id ) && is_page( [ 'home' ] ) ) {

        $posts = wp_get_recent_posts( array(
            'numberposts' => 1,
            'meta_key'    => 'usp-custom-1',
            'meta_value'  => 'question'
        ) );

        if ( !empty( $posts ) ) {
            update_user_meta( $user_id, 'pagehome', array_pop( $posts )->ID );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'wp', 'bt_update_user_homepage_meta' );
```

I've tweaked things:

- I've wrapped it up in the `if ( !empty( $user_id ) && is_page( [ 'home' ] ) )` so that you don't do any of this processing unless the user is logged-in and it's the page "home"
- I use the handy wp lookup function `wp_get_recent_posts` for recent posts that orders them by the newest published, and limit the query to 1 result.
- then I pop it off the array of posts and reference the `ID` to store it into the user meta.

For completeness sake, I should say that you probably shouldn't be doing this on every time the page is loaded as you'll have that extra `get_posts()` query each time, albeit for only logged-in users.  There isn't really an issue with updating the user meta though, since if the value isn't changed, no data is written to the DB.

Comment: Hey Paul G, thanks for your effort, I have actually fixed my code simply putting the `$id = get_the_ID();` inside the query and used your `if ( !empty( $user_id ) && is_page( [ 'home' ] ) )` so that only logged in users on the page "home" would be proccessed. THANKS AGAIN for your time!

Comment: no problem. If my code helped you, please do feel free to vote it or accept. Thanks.